# What's the best way to do a mapping application for the iPhone

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, maps

So I'm looking at writing an iPhone application that shows things on a map. What frameworks/methodologies are out there for doing this?

Searching around on Google, I could only find this one:
http://code.google.com/p/iphone-google-maps-component/

Which according to the issues list is slow, and stops working after a while. Does anyone know of something better, or have any experience with the library above?

Comment: Wonder if you'd invoke the magic app-store competitive function veto?

Comment: I originally wondered that too, but there are lots of mapping applications making it through. I think the main thing to avoid would be real-time guidance stuff, which is explicitly forbidden.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm pretty sure your only options for now are:

1. Call openURL: to switch to the Maps app
2. Use the Google Maps component you linked to
3. Roll your own thing
4. Wait for Apple to expose a "MapKit" framework

Answer (score 2):

WARNING: Embedding Google Maps inside an application *may* violate the Google Maps terms of service.

I *have* written a full mapping UIView on the iPhone (the application is on the AppStore) and it is *not* easy (this would be option #3 "Roll your own thing"). Getting good performance is really difficult. I would like to OpenSource my map component but right now the F-NDA is preventing that.

Comment: I'm sure that if you were to open source it, perhaps anonymously, Apple would be unlikely to chase you down.

Comment: The NDA has been lifted now for published apps...care to share a bit more as to how you did it, and what your app is called?

Answer (score 2):

I have been chasing this for a while now, and here's the best solution I've found out there:

http://code.google.com/p/touchcode/

There is a component in there called TouchMap and it comes with a demo that shows it off. It's tiles are loaded directly from Microsoft Virtual Earth.

Edit: @schwa, I just a look at your profile to find your email address, and then realised that you actually released this software. Nice work

Answer (score 2):

I've just found [route-me](http://code.google.com/p/route-me/) which looks like a large(30+) active community of ppl developing an open source mapping app for the iPhone. It can take tiles from OpenStreetMap, Virtual Earth(Bing) or Cloudmade.

Answer (score 0):

just use mapkit framework.really good

alternatively: `[[uiapplication sharedapplication]openurl:@"www.maps.google.com];`
that will open the google map,but one problem with this is that it will navigate you to safari and your application will be exited and if you want to move back to your application from this web page,then it won't be possible .you again need to run the app.